# Is it possible to set negative width in svg rectangle?

Tags: svg, jquery-svg, rect

i want to move the rectangle based on mouse move. please refer below link.

http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog_media/draw/draw1.html

get rectangle start position in mousedown event and start dragging it will create the rectangle in mouse move event. but when i  moving to previous value (i.e moving to less than mouse down value meas it will return negative value ) so width become negative.

the above link is canvas rectangle. but i have created svg rectangle with same logic.

negative width for rectangle not supported ? or how can i move the rectangle based on mouse move ?

whats going wrong ?

My code snippet.

```
ChartMouseDown:function(e){

//       e = this.normalizeMouseEvent(e);


      var mousedownCords=this.calMousePosition(e);
      this.mouseDownX=mousedownCords.X;
      this.mouseDownY=mousedownCords.Y;

      this.chartMouseDownPoint= this.GetValuebyPoint(Math.abs(this.mouseDownX-this.model.m_AreaBounds.X),Math.abs(this.mouseDownY-(this.model.m_AreaBounds.Y + this.model.m_AreaBounds.Height)));
      this.zoomingX=true;

    },



ChartMouseMove: function (evt) {

    if( this.zoomingX)
    {

    var mouseMoveX,mouseMoveY;

     var mouseMoveCords=this.calMousePosition(evt);
      mouseMoveX=mouseMoveCords.X;
      mouseMoveY=mouseMoveCords.Y;
      $(this.ZoomAreaRect).remove();
      var width =  Math.abs(mouseMoveX - this.mouseDownX);
      var height = mouseMoveY - this.mouseDownY;
      var x;
      if(mouseMoveX > this.mouseDownX)
      x= this.mouseDownX;
      else
      x= mouseMoveX;

       this.ZoomAreaRect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");

        $(this.ZoomAreaRect).attr({
            'id': 'ZoomArea', 'x': x, 'y': this.model.m_AreaBounds.Y, 'width': width, 'height': this.model.m_AreaBounds.Height,
            'fill': 'gray', 'stroke-width': 1, 'stroke':'gray'
        });

       $(this.ZoomAreaRect).appendTo(this.SvgObject);

    }


 calMousePosition:function(e)
    {
     var matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
     var browser = {};
     var mouseX,mouseY;
     if(matched.browser.toLowerCase()=="mozilla")
        {
        mouseX = (e.pageX)-  $(this.SvgObject).parent().offset().left;
        mouseY=  (e.pageY) - $(this.SvgObject).parent().offset().top;
        }
        else
        {
        mouseX =  (e.pageX +document.documentElement.scrollLeft)-$(this.SvgObject).offset().left;
        mouseY =  (e.pageY + document.documentElement.scrollTop) - $(this.SvgObject).offset().top;
        }

        return { X: mouseX, Y:mouseY};

    },
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- The canvas specification places [no restriction on width or height being negative](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-rectangles-to-the-bitmap), so if they were negative the rectangle would draw in the opposite direction.
- The SVG specification says that if width or height are negative then the [rectangle is not drawn](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement).

If you want to implement this in SVG you'll have to make sure the rectangles width/height are always positive and calculate the x/y accordingly.

Comment: problem now is how can we achieve the same effect with SVG?

Comment: @JSmith you can always ask another question but it should be pretty obvious if you think it through.

Comment: I've only found a complex solution. Would have though there would an easier one. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

you can use a polygon instead of a rect, with points as

```
points={`${x},${y} ${x + width},${y} ${x + width},${y + height} ${x},${y + height}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two coordinate arrays start and end, where `(start[0],start[1])` is topleft(or bottomright) and `(end[0],end[1])` is topleft(or bottom right) then this is an algorithm for drawing that rectangle, it doesn't care whether those coordinates get switched

```
              <rect
                fill="rgba(255,0,0,0.3)"
                x={Math.min(start[0], end[0])}
                y={Math.min(start[1], end[1])}
                width={Math.abs(start[0] - end[0])}
                height={Math.abs(start[1] - end[1])}
              />
```